# How to add the end of the first line with the starting of the second line in notepad

Tags: notepad++

i am facing a problem with a list of lines in notepad as follows

i am having 1
0 groceries

i want the line as "i am having 10 groceries"

could any one please help me out using notepad++

Comment: The question is not clear enough about what you want to do and specially where?

Answer (score 1):

**If you just want to remove all new-line characters:**

Go to the Replace window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).

Select "Extended" under "Search Mode".

Find what: `\r\n`
Replace with: (nothing)

Click "Replace All".

`\r\n` is the standard new-line character on Windows. If you want to do this on Linux (or sometimes on Windows too), you may need just `\n`.

This may only work from Notepad++ 6 and onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could join all similar line pairs with a regular expression find and replace.

Enter `(i am having [0-9]+)\r\n([0-9]+ groceries)` into the "Find what" box and enter `\1\2` into the "Replace with" box. Then specify the Search Mode as "Regular Expression".

Changing the Find What text to be `([0-9])\r\n([0-9])` would allow join all lines that have a line-break between two digits.

In both cases I would suggest using the **Replace** button rather than the **Replace-all** to allow easy detection of any lines pairs that should not be joined.